# read text files in different folders in partition and count occurrence of a word using matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, file-io, cpu-word, word-count

I have some text files in different folders that folders named as folder 1 , folder 2 , folder 3 ... etc , these folders in D partition ,

and i have also list of particular words ... i need to count how many that words appear in each text file ( occurrence  ) suppose these occurrence list store in text file or excel file ...

Q : I would be thankful if you can provide any help. ?
this my simple code what i tried

```
for i=1:1000
    fileName = sprintf('A%04d.txt',i);
    A{i} = textread(fileName ,'%s')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what outcome you want, but
this may help:

```
wordList={'and';'are'}; %list of keywords you want to count
wordCount=nan(size(wordList));  %The counts will be here

%file to count words in
fName='rpmTest.m';

%read in the test file
textToCount=textread(fName,'%s');

%for each word in the list, count its occurances
for i=1:length(wordList) 
    wordCount(i)=sum(strcmp(wordList{i},textToCount));
    fprintf('%s: %d\n',wordList{i},wordCount(i));
end
```

I expect the Matlab command of interest to you is "strcmp."

Comment: thank you very much sir its working very well to count the words as you are entered in single file; 
i tested .mat and text file by giving its path , in case in need to parse some folders to check how many these words are occurrences i suppose in my D:\ partition there are 10 folders for example , in case i need to check these folders to see how many text files include these words and print result ... out of all this thank you very much sir